# PHP Permission Denied

Tags: apache-httpd, php, samba

I have a raspberry pi running Apache2, PHP5 and Samba on it (so I can access the pi from my home network as a network drive).

However, I have managed to change the apache2 running directory to `/network-drive/website` in order to be able to build a home website from that directory, which means I can just view the files in windows explorer from my laptop like any other folder.

The problem is, When I log into my pi with the user name `mandy-samba`, The PHP files it saves do not have execute permissions.  When I try and access  index.php, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
```

However If I log in via SSH and run the following command:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /network-drive/website
```

It works fine.

But if I edit the file from my laptop (aka, the mandy-samba user), I get the error.

How can I allow or set my `mandy-samba` user to write files with executable permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the mask/s in your `smb.conf` and restart the samba daemon for the settings take effect.

```
user create mask = 0755 
directory mask = 0775
```

Comment: Ahh wow thank you, Yes I was wondering if it was something to do with the Samba config.  I will try this as soon as I get home tonight! Thank you!